# Javascript Validate domain dot com

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to make a javascript input validator.

I want to check the input if its in the correct domain format. It must check the specific input when the submit button is pressed.

If it is not the correct format, the form will not submit. I am not sure with my RegExp format. Also not sure with the whole code if it will run depending on how i wanted it to be.

Here's my code :

```
var x1=document.forms["leform"]["domain"].value;
 validomain(x1);
function validomain(les) {
    var tdomain = new RegExp('/[:alpha:]+/./[:alpha:]+/');
    if(!tdomain.test(les)){
        alert('not a valid domain format');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you describe the valid domain format?

Comment: what about html5 `<input type='url' / >`?

Comment: that doesn't look like a valid domain format. Either you are wanting to allow for more than just a domain (e.g. a path) or you are misunderstanding how to use `/` as a regex delimiter. Post a couple examples of what you expect the user to actually enter in

Comment: examp.le 
any small letter(probably max 20 chars) dot any small latter again (max 4 chars)

Comment: so, try - var tdomain=/^[a-z]{1,20}\.[a-z]{1,4}$/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your comment:

> examp.le any small letter(probably max 20 chars) dot any small latter
>   again (max 4 chars)

```
var x1=document.forms["leform"]["domain"].value;
 validomain(x1);
function validomain(les) {
    if ( !String(les).match(/^[a-z]{1,20}\.[a-z]{1,4}$/) ) {
        alert('not a valid domain format');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: well, why won't it validate on submit?

Comment: @Gelo103097 probably because something else is wrong with your code. e.g. the `x1` value or maybe you don't even have this attached to your click/submit event in the first place! All I see is you getting a value and calling a function..

Comment: yea, so im also asking if the rest of the code is right, any suggestion to make it work?

Comment: you asked for a valid regex based on your regex requirements, which is what i gave. So the downvote isn't really fair. If you need help on having the function called at the appropriate time and passed an appropriate value, that's a separate question and you need to post details about the actual form

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var tdomain = /^[\w-]+\.\w+$/;
```

\w are word characters.

The . is special (matches any character) and must be escaped.

Also, you might want to research what a valid domain can look like. (Want to match subdomains? what about domains with international characters?)

Comment: don't worry. i only need a domain, not a subdomain, and without international characters.

Comment: I think the last part should not be any word character, only [a-z]{1,4}

Comment: @Gelo103097 also understand that "word" character means more than lowercase letter that you asked for

Comment: also note that without anchor tags, this can match a lot more than you intend. E.g. it will happily match `"foo bar 123 4.6 lots of random stuff"` because `"4.6"` will be matched by this regex

Comment: @GáborBakos True for most domains, but there are TLDs with more than 4 characters, like ".museum". If you include international domains, numbers and dashes must be included. Also, dashes should be included in the main part anyway. (I edited my answer.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: I definitely agree that OP is leaving out a lot of valid domains with the requirements (s)he asked for, but maybe OP only wants domains with the exact requirements listed, for reasons. /shrug

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex too:

```
function validomain(les) {
   var pattern = new RegExp(/([a-z0-9-]+\.(?:com))(?:\/|$)/)
   if(!pattern.test("les"))'{
      alert('not a valid domain format');
      return false;
   }
}
```

@Crayon Violent is right may be you have a problem elsewhere in your code